# MySQL User Defined Constant or Literal for use in CREATE statements

Tags: mysql, macros

I have a script which I use to create all the tables in the database. At the top of the script, I want to define constants which can be used all over the script.

```
SET @moneyD = 6;
SET @priceM = 18; -- 999 billion

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `saver`;

CREATE TABLE `saver`.`test_Symbol` (
    `symbolId` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
    `symbol` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    `dateCreated` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`symbolId`),
    INDEX `symbolIndex` (`symbol` ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE `saver`.`test_SymbolChart` (
    `symbolChartId` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
    `symbolId` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
    `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    `open` DECIMAL(@priceM, @moneyD) NULL,
    `high` DECIMAL(@priceM, @moneyD) NULL,
    `low` DECIMAL(@priceM, @moneyD) NULL,
    `close` DECIMAL(@priceM, @moneyD) NULL,
    `volume` INT NULL,
    `dateCreated` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`symbolChartId`),
    INDEX `symbolIdIndex` (`symbolId` ASC)
);
```

However, this doesn't work because user defined **variables** do not work where a **constant** or **literal** is expected.

How else can I achieve the behavior I desire?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a prepared statement to use variables in this way. Try this:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE `saver`.`test_SymbolChart` ( 
    `symbolChartId` BINARY(16) NOT NULL, 
    `symbolId` BINARY(16) NOT NULL, 
    `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, 
    `open` DECIMAL(', @priceM, ',', @moneyD, ') NULL,
    `high` DECIMAL(', @priceM, ',', @moneyD, ') NULL,
    `low` DECIMAL(', @priceM, ',', @moneyD, ') NULL,
    `close` DECIMAL(', @priceM, ',', @moneyD, ') NULL,
    `volume` INT NULL,
    `dateCreated` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`symbolChartId`),
    INDEX `symbolIdIndex` (`symbolId` ASC)
)');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=90d11e6b1ebff01beba07dd8ac4d6020)

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It works, but I don't like this because I lose syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Croolsby I'll be interested to see if anyone comes up with an alternate solution. I don't know of any other way to use variables in these positions.